# LaTeX Figures in Scientific Workplace

Tags: external-files, scientific-workplace

I'm trying to use Scientific Workplace to compile a document that was written in LaTeX.
Everything is fine but the figures.

In the LaTeX file I wrote

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
```

and

```
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{filename}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This works in LaTeX.

Now I open the same file with Scientific Workplace 5.5 and the problem is that SWP does not find the file `filename`. It recognizes the command `\includegraphics` but it does 
not find the figure file (although it is placed in the working directory and LaTeX can find it)

I have to translate a bunch of files from LaTeX to SWP and I'd like to solve this issue.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. Note that you can format code as code by indenting 4 spaces (easy way: highlight and press '{}' button).

Comment: Hi! I have never seen SWP. Could you please maybe provide a link to some page that shows what it is?

Comment: @tohecz http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26634/.

Comment: Are there any special characters in the file name, besides 0-9, a-z, and A-Z? Also, what happens if you provide the actual file extension to `\includegraphics`?

Comment: I tried to provide the actual file externsion to includegraphics and this is the error message:

Comment: Latex warning: file nomefile.png not found on input line 30

Comment: Are you compiling with pdfLaTeX? If so, does http://www.mackichan.com/pdf.html help?

Comment: Can you please check again if the file really is in your working folder with the filename given?

Comment: Yeah the file is in the right directory. Indeed when I compile the file with tex it works fine. The problem arises when I compile the same tex file using SWP

Comment: I also tried to add